# google dataflow: the type Sum.SumIntegerFn is not visible

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my Eclipse, I've got flagged with error " The type Sum.SumIntegerFn is not visible.

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Sum;
....
something = createAggregator("something", new Sum.SumIntegerFn());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from the import that you're using Apache Beam. You should use [`Sum.ofIntegers()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Sum.java#L119) instead of `new Sum.SumIntegerFn()`.

Also note that in Github head, Aggregators have been removed. Instead, a counter metric will provide similar behavior. See [`Metrics`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/Metrics.java#L63) for more details.

Comment: but I found this from Beam [document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-usercodereqs)  Sum.SumIntegerFn() combines the elements in the input PCollection.
`PCollection<Integer> pc = ...;
PCollection<Integer> sum = pc.apply(
   Combine.globally(new Sum.SumIntegerFn()));`

Comment: The documentation is out of date and the `Sum.SumIntegerFn()` is no longer exposed. `Sum.ofIntegers()` has replaced it. For that use case, you can also do `Sum.integersGlobally()`. The original question was about aggregators, not Combine.

Comment: now I've got this "Sum.ofIntegers cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Are you using `Sum.ofIntegers()` or `new Sum.ofIntegers()`. See the link -- it isn't a type you use with `new` it is a function.

Comment: I've found if I use Metrics `Metrics.counter`, I don't need to use `Sum.ofIntegers()`, correct? do you have an example of using `Sum.ofIntegers()` alone? thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Sum.ofIntegers()`?

Comment: You can either do `something = createAggregator("something", Sum.ofIntegers());`, or you can also use `something = Metrics.counter("counternamespace", "something");`, if you'd like to use metrics counters.

Answer (score 0):

The `Sum.SumIntegerFn()` is no longer exposed publicly, it is replaced by `Sum.ofIntegers()`. If you need a workaround to use your own Iterable function instead of the in-built one, try the code block below.

```
something = createAggregator("something", new SumIntegers());

public static class SumIntegers implements SerializableFunction<Iterable<Integer>, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Iterable<Integer> input) {
            Integer sum = 0;
            for (Integer item : input) {
                sum += item;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```